# define a signature for outgoing messages in outlook using applescript

Tags: outlook, applescript

I searched a lot to find a solution that works for defining a signature for outgoing message created with applescript.
but none of them seems to work.

```
set newMessage to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:("Meeting reminder:" & space & subject1 & space & "@" & space & starttime), content:textstext}
            make new recipient at newMessage with properties {email address:{address:emailadd}}
            set message signature of newMessage to signature "1"
```

I just want to to set to an empty signature as I don't want to use my default one.